# the left hand side of an assignment must be a variable when setting value for an element inside list

Tags: c#, dynamic

I want to set the value of an element at a specific position inside a dynamic list. It returns me with this error. What is the cause of this and how can I fix this?

```
public class DienTieuThuRowModel
{
    public List<dynamic> RowItem { get; set; }
}

DienTieuThuRowModel result = new DienTieuThuRowModel();
result.RowItem = new List<dynamic>(new dynamic[10]);
float variable = 12;
result.RowItem.ElementAt(1) = giatri;
```

Comment: `.ElementAt(1)` is a LINQ method that iterates through the list to the nth item and returns it (even if you could reassign the result, it wouldn't change the list). As you have a list, you simply want `result.RowItem[1] = giatri;`.

Comment: It returns me with another error is that 'Identifier is expected'. Is it because dynamic type? I thought dynamic data type was supposed to handle all kinds of data then return errors later when running.

Comment: I expect it's because `giatri` isn't defined anywhere?

Comment: It works fine if I change `giatri` to `variable` ([example](https://rextester.com/ZYNS41050)).

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad. I forget about the 'dot' thus the code was something like result.RowItem.[1] = giatri; It fixed now.

Answer (score -1):

using @Llama suggestion, I suggest you to cast it to dynamic

```
result.RowItem[1] = (dynamic) giatri;
```

Comment: [Dynamic docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic). You don't need to cast any assignment to a variable declared as `dynamic` because `dynamic` can accept any value.